# ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES - permission denied

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I have a problem with `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`. I grant the permission:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES 
    FOR USER user_name
    IN SCHEMA schema_name
    GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO user_name;
```

in the next step, I create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE schema_name.a (q int);
```

Now, I connect to the database using *conn_user* and try to read the data in the new table:

```
SELECT * FROM schema_name.a
```

and I receive the error:

```
SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: permission denied for relation a
  org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: permission denied for relation a
```

Do you have any ideas why the error appears?

Answer (score 14):

To grant default privileges, you actually need to grant rights to the user you are creating the table with.

e.g.: you're creating the tables as *SA_user*, but reading the tables as *READ_user*.
Your code needs to look like this:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES 
FOR USER SA_user
IN SCHEMA schema_name
GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO READ_user;
```

So whenever the *SA_user* creates a table, it will grant select rights for the *READ_user*.

Answer (score 11):

The problem here is the [`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) statement you issued will apply only to tables that are created by `user_name`:

> You can change default privileges only for objects that will be created by yourself or by roles that you are a member of.

and

> **target_role**
>
> The name of an existing role of which the current role is a member. If FOR ROLE is omitted, the current role is assumed.

So in your case you either use

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES 
    IN SCHEMA schema_name
    GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO user_name;
```

(without the `FOR USER` clause), or create the table as `user_name` (in which case they'll be the owner, therefore no need to grant anything).

In any case, it's a good practice to always create DB objects as a given user, so that the access privileges are predictable.